# Rotate Google Maps Icon causes cropping

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the built in google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW icon.  If I use the rotation property, the arrow gets cropped on the map.  How can I prevent this?  I tried playing around with the anchor and scale property, but those aren't affecting the problem.

Here's the code:

```
var cp2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(somelat, somelng),
    title: "testtitle",
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        rotation: 270,
        scale: 3
    }
});
cp2.setMap(map);
```